# how to bind values from database to gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I am very new to asp.net.Plz help me.

I have a gridview with two columns named-property(template field) and value(template field). I need to bind the property column(ie,gridview- item template(label)) from database table 'properties'.Properties table fields are ID and PropertyName. How can I bind them??

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindView();


            }

                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID,TypeName from ProductTypes", con);
                da1.Fill(dt1);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt1;
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TypeName";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }

        public void BindView()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string sql = "select * from Properties";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
```

aspx code:

```
 asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 52px; top: 230px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 344px">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyName") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: show your gridView aspx Code?

Comment: please check the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aspx page :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" Text='<%#Bind("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPropertyName" Text='<%#Bind("PropertyName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

dt - table column name should be "ID" & "PropertyName".

Comment: Are you getting any error?? keep a breakpoint on dt and check whether its returing table rows or not..

Comment: put a breakpoint and select dt-> right click -> Quick watch -> see whether its returning table rows or it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ur code have any problem

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 52px; top: 230px; position: absolute; height: 133px; width: 344px">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PropertyName") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

ASPX CODE is perfect just addde Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' for textbox

ASPX.CS Code is also having no problem i changed nothing and its working f9

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    BindView();


                }

                //DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                //SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID,TypeName from ProductTypes", con);
                //da1.Fill(dt1);
                //DropDownList1.DataSource = dt1;
                //DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                //DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TypeName";
                //DropDownList1.DataBind();

            }
            public void BindView()
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string sql = "select * from Properties";
                //con.Open();
                //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);

                dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("PROPERTYNAME",typeof(string));

                dt.Rows.Add(25, "propety1");
                dt.Rows.Add(50, "property2");
                dt.Rows.Add(10, "propety3");

               // da.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                //con.Close();
            }
        }
```

send ur perfect error what u got, any exception or warning